# Canvas draw out of screen bug

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on drawing app and I encountered one problem. When user moves out of screen(to taskbar or browser topbar,...) and then moves back on another place, app just draws line to that point. Is there some way how to stop drawing when user moves out and resume when he enters back (without drawing that additional line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add event.preventDefault() to you mouseout handler.

```
    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }
```